# Trying to bind a simple button to an OnClick function in SFGUI

Tags: c++, sfml, sfgui

So, I've just started using SFGUI in my SFML project and I'm struggling to understand how everything works. I've been reading through the hello world tutorial and some of the examples the library itself offers in it's folders.

I am now trying to create a simple button that does something when it detects a left click, but I can't even get that to work properly. The errors window says the `button` variable is not defined in my `OnClick` method, and if I try to send `button` using the parameters of `std::bind` I get the typical "no matching function for...".

In most examples of the library, this problem is solved by using `this` as the second parameter, next to the function name, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

How should this be done?

My code:

```
void pressEnter(){
    button->SetLabel("Tocado"); // FIRST ERROR IN THIS LINE
}

int main(){

    sfg::SFGUI sfgui;

    sf::VideoMode video_mode( 800, 600 );
    sf::RenderWindow rwindow( video_mode, "In-joked - Menu Principal");
    sf::Event event;

    auto button = sfg::Button::Create("Status");
    button->GetSignal(sfg::Button::OnLeftClick).Connect(
            std::bind(&pressEnter, button)); //SECOND ERROR IN THIS LINE

    ...
}
```

The error NetBeans shows for the first line:
"Unable to resolve identifier "button". "button" was not declared in this scope"

And for the second line:

"in file included from

error: no matching function for call to ‘sfg::Signal::Connect(std::_Bind_helper&>::type)’
             std::bind(&pressEnter, button));"

Full error in run console output:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void pressEnter()’:
main.cpp:7:5: error: ‘button’ was not declared in this scope
     button->SetLabel("Tocado");
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:79:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Signal.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Object.hpp:4,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Adjustment.hpp:3,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Widgets.hpp:6,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_check_arity<void (*)(), std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>&>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1439:12:   required from ‘struct std::_Bind_helper<false, void (*)(), std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>&>’
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1462:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__is_socketlike<_Func>::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = void (*)(); _BoundArgs = {std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>&}]’
main.cpp:20:42:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1410:7: error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for function
       static_assert(sizeof...(_BoundArgs) == sizeof...(_Args),
       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:20:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘sfg::Signal::Connect(std::_Bind_helper<false, void (*)(), std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>&>::type)’
             std::bind(&pressEnter, button));
                                           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Object.hpp:4:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Adjustment.hpp:3,
                 from /usr/local/include/SFGUI/Widgets.hpp:6,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/SFGUI/Signal.hpp:40:16: note: candidate: unsigned int sfg::Signal::Connect(std::function<void()>)
   unsigned int Connect( std::function<void()> delegate );
                ^
/usr/local/include/SFGUI/Signal.hpp:40:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (*)(), std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>&>::type {aka std::_Bind<void (*(std::shared_ptr<sfg::Button>))()>}’ to ‘std::function<void()>’
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:78: recipe for target 'build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/manu/NetBeansProjects/GameMenu'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/manu/NetBeansProjects/GameMenu'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 953ms)
```

Comment: You tell `std::bind` to pass the variable `button` as an argument to the `pressEnter` function when it's called. And yet your function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: I know right? The first thing I tried was setting `pressEnter` to receive a parameter, because it seemed odd, but it didn't work. Plus, the tutorials keep it that way.

Comment: If you have errors, first of all show the code that gives errors. Then also include the actual errors you get, in full, complete with possible informational notes, and unedited. Please take some time to  [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I actually red the guide some time ago, but looks like I forgot about the most important parts. Thank you for taking your time nevertheless, I've edited my post and added the errors for each of the two lines, along with the full output from the console.

Answer (score 1):

One choice would be to have your variable in a scope where both can access it.

```
sfg::Button::Ptr button;

void pressEnter(){
    button->SetLabel("Tocado");
}

int main(){

    sfg::SFGUI sfgui;

    sf::VideoMode video_mode( 800, 600 );
    sf::RenderWindow rwindow( video_mode, "In-joked - Menu Principal");
    sf::Event event;

    button = sfg::Button::Create("Status");
    button->GetSignal(sfg::Button::OnLeftClick).Connect(&pressEnter);

    ...
}
```

This is a global variable and probably not the best way to do this, but it will work. How to structure your program to not have global variables is a bit too broad for a Q&A here.